# Concatenating items in a list?

Tags: python

I need to do: Write a function called `concat_list` that accepts a list of strings as an argument and returns a string made up of all elements in the list concatenated together in order. For example, if the argument is `['one', 'two', 'three']`, the return value would be `'onetwothree'`.

When I enter my code:

```
def concat_list(strings):    #idk if a list for a function has to be []
    count = ' '
    for i in strings:
        count +=1 
        return count
```

I get:

```
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects
```

on line 4. However I cannot think of another way to do this, what am I doing wrong and how do I fix it?

Comment: `"".join(strings)`

Comment: [How to debug small programs.](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)
|
[What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/843953)

Your program is telling you that you're trying to add an integer (`1`) to a string (`count`), This cannot be done.

Comment: A few problems with your code: Why do you `return` inside the loop? that means it will always run just one iteration. Also, what you expect will happen when you add a number to a string? Moreover, **why** do you do that? Why add 1? You want to add the strings together, maybe try `count += i`... Also try to give meaningful names. `count` is not a good name for a string (usually...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

count was defined as a string. Is this what you wanted

```
def concat_list(string):
   count = ""
   for i in string:
       count += i
   return count
```

or you can use

```
def concat_list(string)
    return ''.join(string)
```

Comment: Make sure to do `count += str(i)`. If there are other types than String, the code will raise a `TypeError()`

Comment: Ok yea thank you this solved it! didnt realize i could add the 'i' to count thought it had to be ints

Comment: mind taking it as answer?

Answer (score 0):

What you probably want to do is :

```py
def concat_list(strings):
    result = "" # The constructed string
    for msg in strings:
        result += str(msg) # We had each element of the array
    return result # We return the string at the end of the loop
```

Or you can use :

```py
"".join(strings)
```

Comment: The error raised was actually nothing to do with the for loop but instead an issue with the concatenation of integers and strings. Make sure you do `result += str(msg)` so a `TypeError()` is not raised.